# Python: Fetch value from dataframe list with min value from another column list of same dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, min

input dataframe

```
Flow     row         count
Apple   [45,46]     [2,1]
Orange  [13,14]     [1,5]
```

need to find min value of each list column '`count`' and fetch respective row value from row column.

**Expected output:**

```
  Flow   row     count
  Apple    46     1
  Orange   13     1
```

Comment: Is that a list or a set?

Comment: corrected, thanks! it's a list. Also, included Flow column. kindly check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, the list has a function called `index` where you can get the position of the value you want to find. So, by utilizing this function with a `min`, you can get your desired result.

```
df['min_index'] = df['count'].apply(lambda x: x.index(min(x)))
df[['row_res','count_res']] = [[row[j],count[j]] for row, count, j in zip(df['row'], df['count'], df['min_index'])]

     Flow       row   count  min_index  row_res  count_res
0   Apple  [45, 46]  [2, 1]          1       46          1
1  Orange  [13, 14]  [1, 5]          0       13          1
```

Comment: You can manually drop the column after this

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution (the part `.astype('int')` may be unnecessary in your case):

```
df['row'] = list(df.explode(['row', 'count']).reset_index().groupby('flow')
    .apply(lambda x: x['row'][x['count'].astype('int').idxmin()]))

df['count'] = df['count'].map(min)
```

---

A shorter solution than my previous one, based on [`sorted`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/sorted.html) with key:

```
df.assign(row=df.apply(
 lambda x: sorted(x['row'], key=lambda z: x['count'][x['row'].index(z)])[0],axis=1),
       count=df['count'].map(min))
```

---

Output:

```
     flow  row  count
0   apple   46      1
1  orange   13      1
```

Comment: If i want to get the respective count value as another column, how can the above code be edited

Comment: My meanwhile updated code does what you want, @user12345.